# html5 Geolocation прекрасно работает на LocalHost, но на хостинге не работает

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, геолокация

Помогите пожалуйста, бьюсь над этой проблемой уже две недели, но безрезультатно. Написал простой код, который определяет геолокацию пользователя по GPS. Пишу на Asp.net в visual studio. Использовал яндекс api для создания карты. В локалхост все работает отлично. Выложил на два разных хостинга(somee.com и MyAsp.net), на них не работает. Причем браузер даже не спрашивает, разрешить ли сайту использовать геолокацию или нет.Не работает в мазиле, сафари, хроме. Но, что удивительно, сайт работает в IE. Писал в яндекс поддержку, сказали, что не работает в хроме, так как не использую Https. Но у меня же также не работает и в сафари и в других браузерах, а там не нужен https для работы с геолокацией.
Потом просто взял готовый пример от яндекса(из песочницы), на локалхосте работал, на хостингах нет. 
Вот ссылка на пример
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation

Answer (score 1):

не важно яндекс карты или гугл карты , и не важен браузер , для корректного определения геолокации нужен ssl сертификат на домен - https.
вот пояснения гугла по этому поводу.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

Comment: Спасибо, понял. А это трудно вообще перевести сайт на https?

Comment: купить ssl сертификат на свой домен?

Comment: Ну я слышал его можно получить бесплатно. Его же как-то на хост еще установить нужно.

Comment: @Ilya189 установка сертификата на хост выходит за рамки вопроса. Попробуйте поискать в интернете как это делается. Или задайте новый вопрос, если ничего не найдется.